# Windows Script DelayedExtension not Functional

Tags: batch-file

I have written a script to backup a libreoffice Writer file which I use daily for taking notes. The script runs with windows startup and compares the writer file with the last backup file (using xcopy for this) and if any changes were madde, it makes a new local backup copy (up to 100 files) and also makes a Rar archive (using Winrar) and uploads the new backup to Google Drive (using rclone sync).

Now the problem is, despite using the `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`, still the ERRORLEVEL is always 0. For example I wanna know when rclone sync is not successful in uploading the file.

I have tried `if "!errorlevel!" == "0"` , `if !errorlevel! 0` , i`f not errorlevel 1` , for all occurences inside the script but no one worked.
When I delete all the lines above *:mkrar* the !errorlevel! works fine!

I am not professional in windows scripting and just know a few commands and I know my code is not efficient. Just need to find a way to get the correct errorlevel.

```
Setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem ** Check if required text files exist  **
if not exist "D:\Backup\My Private Notes Backup\Last-Backup-Num.txt" goto error
if not exist "D:\Backup\My Private Notes Backup\Compare.txt" goto error
set oldnum=0
rem ** Load the number of the last backup file **
set /P oldnum=<"D:\Backup\My Private Notes Backup\Last-Backup-Num.txt"
rem ** Delete the extra "space" from the last number saved **
set oldnum=%oldnum: =%
echo %oldnum%
set newnum=0
set /A newnum=oldnum+1
if %newnum% GTR 100 set newnum=1
set src=empty
set oldback=D:\Backup\My Private Notes Backup\%oldnum%.odt
set newback=D:\Backup\My Private Notes Backup\%newnum%.odt

rem ** Check if all required odt files exist **
if not exist "E:\My Private Notes.odt" goto error
if not exist "%oldback%" goto error

if not exist "%newback%" goto error

rem ** Compare the source file with the last backup file, to see if new backup is necessary **
xcopy "E:\My Private Notes.odt" "%oldback%" /D /Y /L > "D:\Backup\My Private Notes Backup\Compare.txt"
set /P src=<"D:\Backup\My Private Notes Backup\Compare.txt"
if "%src%"=="E:\My Private Notes.odt" (
rem ** Changes detected, create new backup file **
  xcopy "%src%" "%newback%" /Y
  goto okay
) else (
rem ** No change from the last backup detected **
        exit
)

:okay
rem ** If the file was copied successfully, replace oldnum with newnum and save it as last backup number and run RAR2Drop **
if "!errorlevel!" == "0" (
echo %newnum% >"D:\Backup\My Private Notes Backup\Last-Backup-Num.txt"
goto mkrar
) else ( goto error
)

rem ** Compress the New Backup File into a RAR Archive for Upload **
:mkrar
rem ** The source file is the file just created as backup **
set src="%newback%"
rem ** The Rar file name is the file number of new backup without ".rar" **
set newback="D:\Backup\My Private Notes Backup\%newnum%"
rem ** Delete possible Rar files left from last script run **
del %newnum%.rar
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\winrar.exe" a -ma5 -hp5rte453 -m5 -ibck -ep %newback% %src%
if "!errorlevel!" == "0" (
goto upload
) else ( goto rar-error
)

rem ** Upload the Rar File to Google Drive and Delete the Rar File **
:upload
set newback=%newback%.rar
"D:\Backup\My Private Notes Backup\rclone" --config "D:\\Backup\\My Private Notes Backup\\rclone.conf" copy %newback% remote:MyCisNoBacks
del %newback%
if "!errorlevel!" == "0" (
exit
) else ( goto up-error
)


:error
echo There was an error while copying Private Notes Backup file !
Pause
exit

:rar-error
echo There was an error while creating Rar Archive 4 Private Notes Backup file !
Pause
exit

:up-error
echo There was an error while Uploadin Private Notes Rar Backup file to DropBox !
Pause
exit
```

Comment: Consider using "if errorlevel 1" (which means any error greater than or equal 1" instead. (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576). Also, why do you need delay expansion?

Comment: AFAIR you only need DELAYEDEXPANSION inside loops. In your case you should just check the %errorlevel% normally.

Comment: I am not sure if this is regarding DELAYEDEXPANSION or not, or even if I should use DELAYEDEXPANSION at all?! I tried the normal %errorlevel% and it always returns 0, even if winrar or rclone sync end up with errors.

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly I found what causes the errorlevel to always return 0. The *del %newback%* command which is run after the rclone command causes the errorlevel (which is not rclone's errorlevle anymore) to always return 0.
I moved the *del %newback%* command a couple of lines down in the script and the problem is finished.